# MDX YTD and MTD function have different start date

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, ssrs-2008-r2, olap-cube

I'm new with MDX. Now I need to change an existing SSRS report on a SSAS cube showing values in MTD and YTD.

My problem is that both functions have a different start date for January In this case the starting date of the MTD function is correct

At the moment the MDX code looks like this:

> WITH 
>   MEMBER [value] AS SUM (YTD(), [Measure].[Value]) 
>  
>   MEMBER [value] AS SUM (MTD(), [Measure].[Value])

My problem is that the MTD starts at 2016-01-01 and
my YTD field start at 2016-01-04 , I want that my YTD field also starts in 2016-01-01

In my date dimension i have a calenderyear and a periodyear. It looks like the YTD function uses periodyear, but for the report that I'm building I need the calenderyear.

Can anyone help me with a MDX statement, that will do the same as the YTD function, but starts at the first day of the calenderyear?

Comment: I think those functions will use the first calendar dimension you have in your cube, no way around that. Other than changing the order on the cube. 
You can always do it yourself... if you have a Hierarchy with Year-(...)-Date you can calculate it by yourself as a work around.

Comment: I have a year month Hierarchy with the right dates. How can I create/calculate it myself? But this is not fixable with a periodstodate or parallelperiod function?

Comment: Sure, thats what i mean with "do it yourself" ;)
Small example:
AGGREGATE(
 PeriodsToDate(  
  [Time].[Year - Month - Date].[Year],   
  [Time].[Year - Month - Date].CURRENTMEMBER
 ),
 [Measures].[Sales]
)

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it!!. I used the Hierarchy with the calendar year in the YTD funtion like this YTD([Date].[Month].currentmember) and now I have the correct values

Comment: Great! Good to know. I'll give it a try myself.